# QGIS 3 Python Load all layer from geopackage

Tags: qgis, python, geopackage

I am loading all layers from a geopackage in a QGIS 3 canvas in Python using a list with all layernames and the following code:

```
databasepath = "X:/test.gpkg"
layer = ["1","2","3","4"]    
for i in layer:    
   iface.addVectorLayer(databasepath+"|layername="+i, i, 'ogr')
```

Is there a better way to load all layers from a geopackage beside the list as the layer names or count may change?

Answer (score 5):

The following code uses OGR to read all layers' names in a Geopackage and adds all layers to the current QGIS project:

```
from osgeo import ogr

databasepath = r"X:/test.gpkg"
conn = ogr.Open(databasepath)

for i in conn:
    iface.addVectorLayer(databasepath + "|layername=" + i.GetName(), i.GetName(), 'ogr')
```

Comment: Nice code but is there any way to make sure Database Path can be set in the form of a pop up?